# Widget logic using woocommerce product category

Tags: plugins, widgets, woocommerce-offtopic

orry my question was not clear. I have different category and sub-category.Each categories has sub categories ie.

car-cosmetic

-cream 
-soap

household

-cleaner
-etc.

I would like to display the widget when this category or their children are selected in the menu.

I have tried this but doesn't work

is_product_category( array( 'care-cosmetic', 'household', 'savoury', 'sweet' ) )

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

For the product category page (which is actually a Woocommerce archive type of page) use the condition:

> is_product_category( 'shirts' )

For the product page itself use the condition:

> has_term( "shirts", "product_cat" )